# Update primary key value of a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

There is a table named "User" and UserId is its primary key.I have to update the value of the primary key field "UserId".

As there is only one record in User table and userId for that row of record is "3",I have to update the value with "1".

There are following foreign keys due to which we are not able to update that field.

```
[FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.ApiKeys_ApiKeyId]
 [FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.Clients_ClientId] 
[FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.Languages_LanguageId]
 [FK_dbo.UserProfile_dbo.Countries_UserCountry])
 FOREIGN KEY([ApiKeyId,ClientId,LanguageId,UserCountry])
```

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that? A foreign key maybe? What have you tried?

Comment: yes there are few foreign keys..I am updating the question,please check it.

Comment: I'm guessing the `ClientId` is mapped to the `UserId`? You should drop the foreign key constraint, update the values in both tables and recreate the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I tried "ALTER  TABLE foo WITH NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL)" to drop all constraints but it did't work.

Comment: The proper code would be: `ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP CONSTRAINT <FOREIGN_KEY_NAME>`